# Serverless.yml custom stack with cloudformation output variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless

I am newbie for serverless so pardon me if this is very basic. I am having an issue in which i am creating AMAZON COGNITO POOL and i want to use this userPoolId into my custom stack block to connect it with appsync. Below is my `serverless.yml`

```
 custom:
  accountId: 123xxxxxxxx
  appSync:
    apiId: 123xyzxxxxxxx # only required for update-appsync
    authenticationType: AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS
    userPoolConfig:
      awsRegion: ap-southeast-1
      defaultAction: ALLOW
      userPoolId: (here it only takes string but i want to reference)
  resources:
    Resources:
    # Cognito - User pool
    CognitoUserPool:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
      Properties:
         UserPoolName: abc_xyz_pool
    # Cognito - Client
    CognitoUserPoolClient:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
      Properties:
        ClientName: abc_xyz_pool
        GenerateSecret: false
        UserPoolId:
          Ref: CognitoUserPool
    # Cognito - Identity
    CognitoIdentityPool:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::IdentityPool
      Properties:
        IdentityPoolName: sc_identity_pool
        AllowUnauthenticatedIdentities: false
        CognitoIdentityProviders:
          - ClientId:
              Ref: CognitoUserPoolClient
            ProviderName:
              Fn::GetAtt: [CognitoUserPool, ProviderName]
```

I can reference inside the Resources block but i cannot reference it inside the custom block

Answer (score 2):

The custom block in `serverless.yml` gets evaluated before resources are created and therefore cannot reference those outputs. Even within CFN there are limitations to where and how you reference them.

You can however reference outputs from other CloudFormation stacks.

You should split your serverless project into two projects, the first establishing the user pool, and the second consuming that infrastructure.

In your first project you have your user pool resources, and export the ID for future use in other stacks like so:

```
Resources:
  Outputs:
    MyUserPoolId:
      Value:
        Ref: CognitoUserPool # Key name of user pool resource
      Export:
        Name: MyUserPoolId
```

In your second project that needs the pool ID you would import it:

```
custom:
  appSync:
    userPoolConfig:
      userPoolId:
        Fn::ImportValue: MyUserPoolId
```

Your first project will need to be deployed for the second project to import the exported value.

You can also use ENV variables but that still requires you to establish your user pool first.

Comment: Thank, i am using with ENV variables.

Comment: This is such a great approach, the last thing that I wanted to have was MORE environment variables... It's interesting that one doesn't even need to specify what stack the imported variables come from